# Find distance using accleremoter, gyroscope and Device motion and also use double integration

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, physics, cmmotionmanager, devicemotion

I want to calculate the distance from one point to another point, when I start capturing accelerometer data, and till I stop that, it should gather all samples and should give me distance based on velocity, roll, pitch, yaw and displacement.

I have tried following code based on this [link1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36312/calculation-of-distance-from-measured-acceleration-vs-time) and [link2](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=123128) for double integration.

```
 for (int i = 1; i < [arrXData count]; i++)
 {
     //========================================================================
     //Old Velocity
     double v0 = [[arrVelocity objectAtIndex:(i-1)] doubleValue];

     //Time Data
     double t0 = [[arrTimeData objectAtIndex:(i-1)] doubleValue];
     double t1 = [[arrTimeData objectAtIndex:(i)] doubleValue];

     //Acceleration Data
     double x0 = [[arrXData objectAtIndex:(i-1)] doubleValue];
     double x1 = [[arrXData objectAtIndex:(i)] doubleValue];

    //NewVelocity
    double v1 = v0 + (t1 - t0) * (x0 + x1)/2;
    //========================================================================

    //Old Distance
    double d0 = [[arrDistance objectAtIndex:(i-1)] doubleValue];

    //New Distance
    double d1 = d0 + (x1 - x0) * (v0 + v1)/2;
    //========================================================================
    //Store Distance & Velocity

    [arrVelocity addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:v1]];
    [arrDistance addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d1]];
   //========================================================================
}
```

But the above code gives negative values sometimes, and not sure, whether this gives 100% correct result based on x acclearation values. Here we used x acceleration values after applying filter on it. We used high pass filter for reducing noise on x acceleration.

Does anyone know any algorithm on which we can rely?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is certainly legitimate for the device to return negative values for the acceleration along an axis. If this is confusing then you should bone up on kinematics (the mathematics of motion, see any physics text) before continuing.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841075/find-distance-using-accelerometer-gyroscope-and-device-motion